# Laravel Passport api_token

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with Laravel passport.

My goal is create a Api services through Laravel;
some endpoints that I need it should be protected by authentication.
So, I have followed [this guide](https://medium.com/techcompose/create-rest-api-in-laravel-with-authentication-using-passport-133a1678a876) but there is a problem.

I have created the endpoints: "register" and "login".

They works correctly; when i try to call them through Postman they respond with a auth Token.

But when I try to use the endpoint protected by auth the response is:

> Laravel Passport column “api_token” does not exist

Someone can help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you provide it token?

Comment: Sure :) 
My request's headers is : 

‘headers’ => [
‘Accept’ => ‘application/json’,
‘Authorization’ => ‘Bearer ‘.$accessToken,

]

Answer (score 0):

Laravel/Passport will be looking for a column called `api_token` in one of your tables, this table will be the one that you have specified in your `config/auth.php` file.

[image]

So in this case it will be the `users` table as the value for `provider` shows. You will want to make sure that the column `api_token` is defined in here. This post https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/auth-problem-with-passport will be quite useful for explaining the problem and hopefully solving it!

If you're still struggling or have a bit more insight into what the problem is be sure to ask and I'll try my best to help!

Comment: I already tried to alter my users table adding a column called "api_token"; The result is that now the fatal error has disappeared but the issue still remain because the api_token value on table is always empty. 
So in any case the user has not authenticated

Comment: @MarcoBaroni The api_token for the user should be generated when they register. E.g when you are building your user model to save to your database you should set their api_token to a random string using str_random(). This will have a 99.99% chance of being unique so it is pretty safe. Therefore your users will always have an api_token set as soon as they register for the first time.

Also, if your register user is also an endpoint, you will need to remove this from your auth guarded endpoints because obviously they can't have an api_token if they don't exist yet.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Here's the problem I have with writing the token to the api_token field when it's created.... Passport won't give you the token in it's listener hooks. How the heck do you capture the token and write it to the api_token field? The AccessTokenCreated class has a "tokenId" but that's not the actual token, but an id. But passport isn't giving the oauth/token call the id, but the full bearer token. So when you make subsequent calls using the Bearer Token auth type it fails to find the api_token. It seems like Laravel &^$^ed up the Passport module with version 7.x